# (PHP) Verifying if given date is between two other dates

Tags: php, date

I'm having an issue with some code that someone else has previously worked on.
The goal is to iterate through a directory and push any files that are within a certain date range to an array (files are in mmddyyy.txt format).
The (terribly named, not by my own doing) variables in the code represent the following:

- $aYear - A given year, read in from a text file. This variable changes during every iteration of the loop. The same goes for $aMonth and $aDay.
- $sYear1 - Start year. $sMonth1 and $sDay1 are used in respect to $sYear1.
- $sYear2 - End year. $sMonth2 and $sDay2 are used in respect to $sYear2.
- $isGood - File will be added to the array.

  ```
  $isGood = false;
          if($aYear >= $sYear1 && $aYear <= $sYear2)
          {
              if($aYear == $sYear1)
              {
                  if($aMonth == $sMonth1)
                  {
                      if($aDay >= $sDay1 && $aDay <= $sDay2)
                      {
                          $isGood = true;
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if($aMonth >= $sMonth1 && $aMonth <= $sMonth2)
                      {
                          $isGood = true;
                      }
                  }
              }
              else if($aYear == $sYear2)
              {
                  if($aMonth == $sMonth2)
                  {
                      if($aDay <= $sDay2)
                      {
                          $isGood = true;
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if($aMonth <= $sMonth2)
                      {
                          $isGood = true;
                      }
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  $isGood = true;
              }
          }

          if($isGood)
          {
              //echo "Found good article";
              $a = $a . "===" . $file;
              array_push($result, $a);
          }
  ```

I'm not getting the results that I expected. I'm looking for some help as to how I can simplify this code and get it working properly. I do need to keep this solution in PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're not getting the results you expect?

Comment: What results are you getting? What results are you expecting?

Comment: @squints as in values for variables that don't work the way you expect them to. Also, yes this can be cleaned up dramatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sandeep pointed out you're issues are with:

```
if ($aMonth >= $sMonth1 && $aMonth <= $sMonth2)
```

and

```
if ($aDay >= $sDay1 && $aDay <= $sDay2)
```

as you don't need to be comparing the date with end dates as well.

That being said you can clear up your code completely by doing something like:

```
$date = (new DateTime)->setDate($aYear, $aMonth, $aDay);
$start = (new DateTime)->setDate($sYear1, $sMonth1, $sDay1);
$end = (new DateTime)->setDate($sYear2, $sMonth2, $sDay2);

if ($start <= $date && $date <= $end) {
    //echo "Found good article";
    $a = $a . "===" . $file;
    array_push($result, $a);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The odd part of this question that I should've mentioned is that we're not looking at this from a date perspective; the day, month and year are each integers. For example, a start month of January 5th, 2016 would make $sMonth1 = 1, $sDay1 = 5 and $sYear1 = 2016.

Comment: @Squints Ok, and I'm using those values for create the `DateTimes` to do what you if statements were doing. Have you tried my answer and it's not working?

Comment: This really pushed us in the correct direction, thank you. Our PHP server was having issues with DateTime for some reason, so we settled with strtotime(). The problem is solved, thanks for your input!

Comment: @Squints Are you using PHP 5.1 or lower?

Comment: We're using PHP 5.2.6

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me Month statement  if($aMonth >= $sMonth1 && $aMonth <= $sMonth2) needs work
eg start date- 03 Aug 2013 end date- 04 Sep 2016 and check date say 08 Nov 2013
would make isGood=false whereas it should be true.

Removing *&& $aDay <= $sDay2* and *&& $aMonth <= $sMonth2* should work.